# Remove unicode in MFC windows application

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

During create MFC application I have selected `Use Unicode libraries` option in Application types. Now I decided not to use Unicode , but I can't find in code where should be removed. Would you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can I enquire why you have chosen not to use Unicode? Once you get the hang of it, it's barely different from Ansi/Multibyte and will accept native language input seamlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have VS 2012, but it should be quite similar:

You can select it under your project properties screen.

> Project> Properties>  Configuration properties> general > Character set > Use unicode or MBS character set

Hope this will help.

Comment: The location until Visual Studio 2010 is correct, but I'm not sure if it is possible to get rid of UnicodeCS if you select it from Project Wizard. Waiting for confirmation.

Comment: vs 2019 Project> Properties> Configuration properties>advance> Character set  to not set